# connect frontend to backend

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express

I am new and trying to practice as a full stack web developer but I am stuck with a problem like a typing competition. I need to show the message that I type in the message form, like if I type "k" - it should give me a k letter below the message form (which happens when we practice typing).

I tried to do this with a submit button. When I click on submit, it shows the message. But I want the message instantly(without any click).

Could anybody suggest any site where I can learn this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: "*I need to show the message that I type in the message form instantly*" – Show it where? What is a "typing competition"? I really don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use socket.io, with this quick start tutorial: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for MEAN Stack development, where your backend is managed using Node and you can use angular as front end or simple html javascript you can try with.

Watch this video it will help you is this.

[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJAkjtXLyLw)